# tkz-euclide: points render "under" lines

Tags: tkz-euclide

When building a figure using the `tkz-euclide` package within the `tufte-handout` class, some points lie "underneath" intersecting lines, while other points lie "on top" of intersecting lines in the rendered output.

For example, when running this code (from the package documentation) for the "Golden Triangle,"

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){D}
\tkzDefSquare(C,D)
\tkzGetPoints{e}{f}
\tkzDefMidPoint(C,f)
\tkzGetPoint{m}
\tkzInterLC(C,f)(m,e)
\tkzGetSecondPoint{n}
\tkzInterCC[with nodes](C,C,n)(D,C,n) \tkzGetFirstPoint{B}
\tkzInterLC(C,D)(D,B) \tkzGetSecondPoint{A}
\tkzInterLC(B,A)(B,D) \tkzGetSecondPoint{E} \tkzInterLL(B,D)(C,E) \tkzGetPoint{F} \tkzDrawPoints(C,D,B) \tkzDrawPolygon(B,...,D) \tkzDrawPolygon(B,C,D)
\tkzDrawSegments(D,A A,B C,E) \tkzDrawArc[delta=10](B,C)(E) \tkzDrawPoints(A,...,F) \tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=blue!20](B,F,C) \tkzFillAngles[fill=blue!10](C,B,D E,A,D) \tkzMarkAngles(C,B,D E,A,D) \tkzLabelAngles[pos=1.5](C,B,D E,A,D){$\alpha$} \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,C,D,E) \tkzLabelPoints[above right](B,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

this image results:

[image]

If you look closely, points A, B and F exhibit this description.

How do I correct this?

Comment: It is recommended to provide a complete example, also called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), rather than code snippets.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I will remember to do this in my following questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are drawn in the order in which they appear in the code (unless layers are specified for parts of the code), so to get the points drawn on top, it's simply a matter of moving `\tkzDrawPoints(A,...,F)` to the very end of the the diagram, after all the other parts. (You can remove the `\tkzDrawPoints(C,D,B)` by the way, that is redundant.)

I'd also suggest drawing the lines after the `\tkzFillAngles` and `\tkzMarkRightAngle`, currently the filling cover half the lines.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){D}
\tkzDefSquare(C,D)
\tkzGetPoints{e}{f}
\tkzDefMidPoint(C,f)
\tkzGetPoint{m}
\tkzInterLC(C,f)(m,e)
\tkzGetSecondPoint{n}
\tkzInterCC[with nodes](C,C,n)(D,C,n) \tkzGetFirstPoint{B}
\tkzInterLC(C,D)(D,B) \tkzGetSecondPoint{A}
\tkzInterLC(B,A)(B,D) \tkzGetSecondPoint{E} \tkzInterLL(B,D)(C,E) \tkzGetPoint{F}   
\tkzDrawArc[delta=10](B,C)(E) 
\tkzMarkRightAngle[fill=blue!20](B,F,C)
\tkzFillAngles[fill=blue!10](C,B,D E,A,D)
\tkzMarkAngles(C,B,D E,A,D)
\tkzLabelAngles[pos=1.5](C,B,D E,A,D){$\alpha$}
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,C,D,E)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](B,F)

\tkzDrawSegments(D,A A,B C,E)
\tkzDrawPolygon(B,C,D)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,...,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second part of your answer fulfills what I want to append to my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Draw points after angle filling. That is, move `\tkzDrawPoints` after corresponding `\tkzFillAngles`.

PS: Your example is very similar to the second example in [`tkz-euclide` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/TKZdoc-euclide.pdf), sec. 1.3.1 *Example Part I: gold triangle*. You can learn the command order used in package manual.